# Error 403 with Google Translate v2 API access

Tags: android, api, google-translate

I am trying to access Google's Translate services from within an Android app. However, each time I try to access the service (using an `HttpGet` request), I encounter the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

I am not able to resolve the above error. I have set up the project as follows:
1. On the Google Developer's Console, created a new project.
2. From the "APIs and Auth" section on the left, activated the Translate API v2.
3. Generated the SHA1 key with debug.keystore and on the Developer's Console, generated a new key with this information.
4. Added billing information. Credit card has been accepted.
5. Used the following link to access Translate API:
`https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=myKey&source=en&target=hi&q=hell`

Each time the app runs the above Get Request, the 403 error is returned. I have been through all the links that SO or Google can care to throw up on this issue and nothing seems to have affected it.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Not sure about that but `debug.keystore` might be wrong. You typically want to setup things with the release key since that's the key your released app uses to authenticate.

Comment: @Sriram were you able to solve this?

Comment: @AhmedZ.: No. No luck.

Comment: @Sriram Ohhhh very big one...

Answer (score 0):

Because you restricted your api key with your android app (package name and SHA certificate), you must include these information to the header of each request sending to google.

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989062/restricting-usage-for-an-android-key-for-a-google-api/42851756#42851756).